# create a substring of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my view i have the following:

```
<% @files.each do |f| -%>
    <% str = f.split("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/downloads/") %>
    <% =str% ><br>
<% end -%>
```

each file name that is output is preceeded by "/public/downloads/". i have tried numerous functions but can't seem to find a function that works to get rid of it.

Thanks.

Comment: What does @files array consist of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<% @files.each do |f| -%>
<% str = f.gsub(/^.*\//, '') %>
<% =str% ><br>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: hi psyho. this produces the same results including "/public/downloads/" prior to the file name. thanks tho.

Comment: that works perfectly. read up on gsub and could not get it to work myself. with the regexp you supplied... i think i understand how it works now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `basename`?

```
Pathname.new(str).basename.to_s
```

update:

```
<% @files.each do |f| -%>
    <% str = Pathname.new(f).basename.to_s %>
    <%= str %><br>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: tried so many variations... getting "can't convert Array into String" to this and other variations: newstr = Pathname.new(str).basename.to_s